# Getting the convert value of type 'String' to 'Calendar.Identifier' error after converting Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: swift

After converting (my working previously) code to `SWIFT 3` I am getting an error message while trying to compile and run:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
>   'Calendar.Identifier'

Pasting the section the issue occurs:

```
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    var birthday = calendar?.date(from: dateComponent)
    var currentDate = Date()
```

Adn the whole App/code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { //, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var dayTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var monthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var yearTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

/*UI Picker data

var data = */

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    textField.inputView = datePicker
} */


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dayTextField.delegate = self //dopisujemy delegate i u góry uitextfielddelegate
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}




//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    messageLabel.text = "Udało się!"

    var dateComponent = DateComponents()
    dateComponent.day =  Int(dayTextField.text!)! //1
    dateComponent.month = Int(monthTextField.text!)! //1
    dateComponent.year = Int(yearTextField.text!)! //2000


    //TextField - zamykanie klawiatury po nacisnieciu na ekran poza klawą






    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    var birthday = calendar?.date(from: dateComponent)
    var currentDate = Date()






    //obie następne rzeczy printowane sa w konsoli XCode po naciśnieciu przycisku w aplikcaji
    print(birthday)
    print("Current Date is \(currentDate)")



    //sumowanie
    var datesDuration = (calendar as NSCalendar?)?.components(NSCalendar.Unit.day,
                                             from: birthday!,
                                             to: currentDate, options: [])



    //poniżej ! oznacza, iż nie jest to optional tylko na pewno var. Gdyby zostało ?, przy wyniku pojawił by nam się w aplikacji "otpional".

    var daysTogether = datesDuration!.day


    /*dodamy bajery aby było bardziej ładnie

    var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    var dayString = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(daysTogether) */


    //wynik koncowy
    messageLabel.text = "Dni w związku: \(daysTogether) !! "



}

/*UIPicker nieskonczony

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {


}


@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

} */


}
```

Comment: Write this:-  `var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` & Study this [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1412400-init)

Answer (score 2):

The [`init(identifier:)` failable initialize of `Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1412400-init) expects a single argument of type `NSCalendar.Identifier`:

> ```
> init?(identifier calendarIdentifierConstant: NSCalendar.Identifier)
> ```

In Swift 3, the [calendar identifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1652687-calendar_identifiers) that you want to make use of (in your case) is `Calendar.Identifier.gregorian`. I.e.

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
```

or, simply

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

Comment: Thank You, that solved my issue. Now the code compiles and launches successfully agaian ! :)

Comment: @M.Spoldi happy to help!

Comment: can i set globally. my app is old and I have big project.. and I have used calendar so many places.

Answer (score 0):

change to the following

`var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)`

[valid types for Calendar in swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar.identifier)

Comment: can i set globally. my app is old and I have big project.. and I have used calendar so many places.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a singleton so that way you can access the one calendar object from any class

Comment: you are right it's working but my project is 5 years old and 100 places used calendar in my project.. I have to set default gregorian.any sort cut method for this..method overriding or somthing else.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a singleton so that way you can access the one calendar object from any class then replacing all of your calendar references with the singleton